# Getting <h1> from a list of websites and putting into a list box

Tags: vb.net, http

I need help getting the h1 off of a list of sites within the header section, and putting it into list boxes in Visual Basic/Studio.

The number of sites amount to a somewhat high number, so I would expect there to be multi-threading, or something else involved.

Example of website html header:

```
<header> 
            <a href="http://www.example.org/"><h1>Exmaple header I NEED TO GET THIS</h1></a>
            <p>Example and more gibberish below</p>
            <div class="hero-unit">
                <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#download" class="btn btn-large btn-download"><i class="icon-unlock icon-white"></i> Instant Download</button>
                <div id="download" class="modal hide fade" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h3>Blahblahblargh</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" id="gw_content">
                        <img src="./landingpage/_img/wheel-throb.gif" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <p>Derp</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>meow</p>
            </div>
```

I need to get the h1 from the code above.

I do apologize as this may be somewhat complex, I plan on expanding on this greatly and I think this will benefit my self-learning experience.

I do know the basics of Visual Studio, so don't think you have to teach me how to make forms :)

Edit:

I only need the h1 tag from the header. Thanks!

Comment: Here something to keep in mind, what if there is more than 1 <h1>  in the HTML? There is a great chance this could exist more than once, but would be good if you want all <h1> tags in the HTML...

Answer (score 1):

You should try the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples) to parse the HTML code.
It can be easily installed through the `NuGet Package Manager` AddIn.

Once you have installed the package, and researched some of its functionality, I'd recommend using a tool such as [HAPTestbed](http://haptestbed.codeplex.com/) to test your regular expressions. It will save you tons of time.

---

Here's a basic sample which you could use as a starting point:

```
Dim wc As New WebClient()
Dim html = wc.DownloadString("http://some-web-site.com/")
wc.Dispose()
Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlDocument()
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html)
For Each h1Node In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h1")
    ' Do Something...
Next
```